# No sound from Superior Drummer in Reaper

Tags: vst, reaper

I have been scouring the web for an answer to this.

I am trying to use Superior Drummer 2 in Reaper to replace my MIDI drums with real drums, however I am not getting any playback from my VST.

When I load it up in Toontrack Solo, everything plays back perfectly, but in Reaper it is silent even though I see the levels move.

The MIDI drums playback fine through Reaper, but they are not replaced. I have the AISO setup, MIDI output hardware is set on all the tracks. Everything seems to be set up the same way as any of the forums or Youtube tutorials.

Comment: Just for kicks, what happens if you create a new track receiving the midi track?

Comment: Click in the little speaker to activate monitoring?